# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' Epicor10

Tags: linq

I have piece of code converted to C# in Epicor10.
The on board compiler allows for this code, but when it is triggered from the API I receive:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I have it narrowed down to this part of my where clause:

```
&& string.Compare((string)Part_Row["ShortChar01"] ,(string)"None",true)!=0
```

it is part of this snippet:

```
 var ttRcvDtlRow = ttRcvDtl_iterator;
    foreach (var Part_iterator in (from Part_Row in Db.Part
                                   where string.Compare(Part_Row.Company, ttRcvDtlRow.Company, true) == 0
                                   && string.Compare(Part_Row.PartNum, ttRcvDtlRow.PartNum, true) == 0
                                   /*&& string.Compare((string)Part_Row["ShortChar01"] ,"None",true)!=0*/
                                                                     && string.Compare((string)Part_Row["ShortChar01"] ,(string)"None",true)!=0 
                                           select Part_Row))
```

Suggestions on how to fix. I understand from other posts that this happens b/c linq is sending this to SQL and there is a problem in the translating (or something similar)

Indexer?

```
Erp.Tables.Part Part;
foreach (var ttRcvDtl_iterator in (from ttRcvDtl_Row in ttRcvDtl
                               where (string.Equals(ttRcvDtl_Row.RowMod, IceRow.ROWSTATE_ADDED, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || string.Equals(ttRcvDtl_Row.RowMod, IceRow.ROWSTATE_UPDATED, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                               && String.IsNullOrEmpty(ttRcvDtl_Row.LotNum)
                               select ttRcvDtl_Row))
```

Thanks,
JM

Comment: What is the type of `Part_Row`? And can you show the code of the indexer? There must be way to rewrite this into a `FirstOrDefault(expression)`.

Comment: Please edit the question. Code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: Sorry new to this.

Comment: Should be there now in the right format

Comment: Try to replace `Part_Row["ShortChar01"]` by the LINQ statement in the indexer. It's hard to piece together what your code looks like without seeing the class model. Next question would be, what is `ttRcvDtl`? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

"I understand from other posts that this happens b/c linq is sending this to SQL and there is a problem in the translating"

That is exactly what's happening. EF doesn't know how to convert `string.Compare` into a SQL method.

```
&& string.Compare((string)Part_Row["ShortChar01"] ,(string)"None",true)!=0
```

should be

```
&& ((string)Part_Row["ShortChar01"]).ToLower() != "none"
```

Depending on your SQL Server settings, you don't even need the ToLower(), as you can set all string comparisons to be case insensitive by default.

Comment: The exception OP is getting is definitely not caused by `string.Compare`, but obviously by `Part_Row["ShortChar01"]` (`'System.Object get_Item(System.String)` aka indexer)

Comment: Yes, his error points to that, but I'm convinced it's due to the string.Compare. EF doesn't know how to handle that (at least the last time I used EF).

Comment: *last time I used EF* That must have been pre-4.1...  It really is the indexer.